# multiple adjacency matrices for one edgelist R

Tags: r, adjacency-list, adjacency-matrix

I have the following edge `list` with a number that associates the edge with a path number. This is given by the following `matrix` which I call *Totallist*: 
`

```
Begin edge  end edge  path number
1               3           1
3               4           1
4               5           1
6               3           2
3               2           2`
```

I want to construct adjacency `matrices` for each of the paths. In this example, I want two `matrices`, but there could be more. I have written the following but it only finds the `matrix` for the first path. I am unsure how to write something that will work for any number of paths that I throw at it:

```
 X<-as.data.frame(table(Totallist[,3]))

nlines<-nrow(X)
nlines
freq<-X[1,2]

diameterofmatrix<-max(Totallist)

X1<-get.adjacency(graph.edgelist(as.matrix(Totallist[1:X[1,2],1:2]), directed=FALSE))
X1<-rbind(X1, 0)
X1<-cbind(X1, 0)
X1
```

I also need the `matrices` to all be the same dimension so that is why I added an extra row and column. I could continue using my method but it seems quite ugly. Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the adjacency matrices into a list you can do the following (I generate some fake data):

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(beginEdge = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE), 
                 endEdge = sample(1:10, 10, replace=TRUE), 
                 pathNum = rep(c(1,2), each=5))
df

      beginEdge endEdge pathNum
1         10       5       1
2         10       8       1
3          3      10       1
4          9       3       1
5          7       5       1
6          6      10       2
7          8      10       2
8          2       2       2
9          7       5       2
10         8       6       2


paths <- unique(df$pathNum) # get the paths to iterate through
```

If we make the nodes factors, and set the levels of the factors to all the nodes in the population, then the adjacency matrices will be computed for the population in your network. I am assuming here the network is ten actors. If your observed data contains all the nodes you want to work with set the levels to `unique(c(df$beginEdge,df$endEdge))`, or whatever the set of nodes are that you prefer.

```
df$beginEdge <- factor(df$beginEdge, levels=1:10) 
df$endEdge <- factor(df$endEdge, levels=1:10)
```

We now go across the list of paths and create matrices storing them as a list:

```
  list.of.adj.mats <- lapply(paths, function(i){
      matrix(as.numeric((
      table(df$beginEdge[df$pathNum==i],
        df$endEdge[df$pathNum==i])+
      table(df$endEdge[df$pathNum==i],
      df$beginEdge[df$pathNum==i]))>0), 
  nrow=length(levels(df$beginEdge)))})
list.of.adj.mats
[[1]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     1
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     1
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1
 [9,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[10,]    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    1    0     0

[[2]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     1
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     1
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0     0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. Just looking at the adjacency matrices your answer gives, I believe they should be symmetric along the diagonal. In other words the entry [i,j]= entry [j,i]. This does not seem to be the case in your answer?

Comment: The example you gave is to compute an undirected adjacency matrix so it is not necessary for it to be symmetric - the matrices I produced encode all the information needed in an undirected adjacency matrix to represent the paths. However, I edited the code to produce symmetric matrices in case that is what you need (although it makes it a bit messier).

Comment: Thank you very much, I should have mentioned I needed symmetric adjacent matrices.